# IIS 7 Application Pool configuration for executing command line interpreter

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I am facing a strange issue with my site in `IIS 7`. I have 10 sites with different sub-domains hosted on IIS 7. I am using `.NET framework 3.5` and `SQL Server 2008 R2`. Three sites I have configured on `DefaultAppPool` while for others I have created `separate application pool for each` and configured them with their specific.

I allows user to upload video, after upload completes I used to `hint` it `(a process to make bit rates of video equal for on-line streaming on android)` using `MP4BOX - a command line interpreter`,  with server side code.

What issue I am facing is while using `DefaultAppPool` the `MP4BOX` works fine but when I configured site to its specific `appPool,` `MP4BOX` stops working. I have go through the `settings` but haven't find any issue. Can anyone help me to overcome this issue.

Awaiting for your valuable response.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No. Just command line interpreter does not follow the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it myself by `assigning read/writes permission to the application pool to the  directory`.
After lots of research I have found that it was happening due to read/write permission of this `exe` to the specific directory. `MP4BOX` need to have read/write permission to create video file in the IIS directory. So I have added application pool as a user to the specific directory to which `mp4box` was accessing for read write.